# How to start a loop with a specific iterator

Tags: python

I want to loop through a list in several loops always starting with the item of the last loop:

```
import itertools as it
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a=iter(list1)
while a.next()!= 8:
    a,b=it.tee(a) #copy the iterator
    while b.next()!=8:
        b,c=it.tee(b)
        while c.next()!=8:
            print "yaaay"
```

in this code I can start my loop with the current iterator of the outer loop. How to do this in a more pythonic way not using slice?

here is an example of what I'm thinking of a more pythonic way:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a=iter(list1)
for k1 in list1:
    for k2=k1 in list1:
        for k3=k2 in list1:
            print "yaaay"
```

Comment: Wait...what are you doing again?

Comment: Would you edit your original post and elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish? Thanks.

Comment: in the inner loop i want to start with the iterator of the outerloop, for example when I'm on the 3th item in the outer loop I want to start also with the 3th item in the inner loop.

Comment: assignment statements in for-in loop is error, `for k3=k2 in list1`

Comment: Ashwini Chaudhary: sure thats an error. thats why im asking how to do it! the first example I gave will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, you're looking for the way to "save" the generator state at some point and then "restore" it. Using `tee` is the correct idea, [PEP 0323](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0323/) has more info on this.

```
import itertools

lst = range(10)
it = iter(lst)

while True:
    print it.next(), '>>',
    it, saved = itertools.tee(it)
    for subitem in it:
        print subitem,
    it = saved
    print
```

Update:

```
import itertools

class fancy_it(object):
    stack = []

    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        if not iterable:
            prev = fancy_it.stack[-1]
            prev.it, iterable = itertools.tee(prev.it)
        self.it = iter(iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        fancy_it.stack.append(self)
        try:
            while True:
                yield self.it.next()
        except StopIteration:
            fancy_it.stack.pop()
            raise StopIteration


for x in fancy_it(range(10)):
    print x
    for y in fancy_it():
        print '**', y
        for z in fancy_it():
            print '****', z
```

Comment: well im not really contented but I guess there is no better solution

Comment: Thats awesome. Thanks thg435, that's a nice implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement), which will loop over the same set of elements but in a single for-loop instead of three:

```
import itertools
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for k1, k2, k3 in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(list1, 3):
     print k1, k2, k3
```

To turn it into the equivalent of three for loops again, you could use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) like so:

```
import itertools
import operator

list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
combos = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(list1, 3)

for k1, k1_groups in itertools.groupby(combos, operator.itemgetter(0)):
    for k2, k2_groups in itertools.groupby(k1_groups, operator.itemgetter(1)):
        print k1, k2, '==>',
        for _, _, k3 in k2_groups:
            print k3,
        print
```

This prints out

```
1 1 ==> 1 2 3 4 5
1 2 ==> 2 3 4 5
1 3 ==> 3 4 5
1 4 ==> 4 5
1 5 ==> 5
2 2 ==> 2 3 4 5
2 3 ==> 3 4 5
2 4 ==> 4 5
2 5 ==> 5
3 3 ==> 3 4 5
3 4 ==> 4 5
3 5 ==> 5
4 4 ==> 4 5
4 5 ==> 5
5 5 ==> 5
```

Comment: the problem hereby is that you can't do manipulations in between, for examble if you want some condition on k2 but not on k1.

Comment: That's true, but you could combine it with `itertools.groupby` if you wanted. I'll edit to show that. (That is getting a little bit silly, though.)

Comment: but thats no flexible at all. As thg435 pointed out, I want to "save" the generator state.

Comment: @varantir I'm not sure how this approach is less flexible: what would you do with the `tee` approach that you can't do here? Of course, if you really do need to save the generator state, `tee` is how to do it, and either your original approach with `tee` or thg435's answer is the best way that I know how to do it -- but I don't see why you'd need to do that.

Comment: Lets say I wanted to delete some of the elements. I think your approach wouldn't support that, because it would change the behavior of groupby.

Comment: That's true: `combinations_with_replacement` actually apparently [consumes the full input iterator into a tuple](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l2306) and then uses that, so modifying the sequence during iteration wouldn't work. If you need to be able to do that, then something based on `tee` is your only option AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [...]
for i, k1 in enumerate(l):
    for i, k2 in enumerate(l[i:]):
        # this loop skippes the elements after k1
        ...
```

Comment: slicing is expensive. (...not using slice)